# bind multiple parameter in php

Tags: php, mysql

This query works

```
SELECT id, username, password 
        FROM users
       WHERE (email = ?)
        LIMIT 1"
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
```

This does not

```
SELECT id, username, password 
        FROM users
       WHERE (email = ? || username = ?)
        LIMIT 1"
```

Need to log in using both email as well as username having trouble in login in using only email

Comment: Please, just read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. And the to-much-code protection isn't just a way for you so you can add a lot of a's so your post got accepted

Answer (score 1):

USE OR instead of ||

```
SELECT id, username, password 
        FROM users
       WHERE (email = ? OR username = ?)
        LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring parameters, you can list all the types and then variables following it, example below;

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE (email = ? OR username = ?) LIMIT 1"

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $username);
```

Additionally, as Shahnawaz said, use OR instead of ||.